# Basic Auth request to a Kong api gateway endpoint gets CORS error and Preflight not found

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, cors, kong

I have a set of micro services and on the edge, I have an API Gateway (Kong **version: _format_version: "1.1"** (kong.yaml file) - kong container use image: "**${KONG_DOCKER_TAG:-kong:2.3.3}**") that expose the routes of the services (like the basic auth **"/api/client/authenticate"** from the client service). I have an web application (frontend) based in vuejs, that comunicates with backend by the API Gateway (Kong).

In my web app (frontend) I make a Basic Auth request (POST) like that:

```
const headers = { 
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password)
};
axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + '/api/client/authenticate', {}, { headers })
```

But I gets 2 errors:

Network tab:
[image: errors]

Console tab:
[image]

My backend services (like client service, responsible for the authentication) is based in Spring Boot, and I use @CrossOrigin annotation in all controller classes. I tested the request directly to the service (without API Gateway (Kong)) and it works as expected, then the problem is the API Gateway (Kong). Other requests that do not need authentication headers work correctly.

My kong.yaml configuration (important parts to this problem, service and CORS plugin configurations):

1 - The **client service**, responsible for the client **authentication**, that exposes the route "/api/client/authenticate":

[image: the client service - authentication service that exposes the route "/api/client/authenticate"]

2 - CORS plugin configuration:

[image: CORS plugin configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that CORS mechanism before each request, makes an preflight request using http **OPTIONS** method.

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) website:

> CORS also relies on a mechanism by which browsers make a "preflight" request to the server hosting the cross-origin resource, in order to check that the server will permit the actual request. In that preflight, the browser sends headers that indicate the HTTP method and headers that will be used in the actual request.

[**SOLUTION**]

Then, to fix this problem we need to expose for each route the http OPTIONS method. Then, in the API gateway configuration file (kong.ymal) for each route I created a copy of the route (named route_name_preflight) with http **OPTIONS** method and **without plugins and authentications** as you can see bellow (kong.yaml):

[image: added preflight route for each route]

It is important to reinforce that as I said above, my backend microservices controller classes have **@CrossOrigin** annotation, that probably **exposes the preflight request for each controller request**, this being necessary.

In the frontend app (vuejs) I started using axios() instead of axios.method(), because is better for add headers (f.e. Authorization with jwt tokens) and other stuff:

```
const options = {
    url: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + '/api/client/authenticate',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password),
    }
};
await axios(options).then(...)
```